# Django 1.8 custom manager and .create() method is not used by .update_or_create()

Tags: django, django-models, django-1.8

I have two related instances that should always be created together. *I'd like to do this without using signals or override the model's `save()` method*.

```
class Car(models.Mode):
    make = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=32)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('make', 'model',)

    objects = CarManager()

class CarProfile(models.Model):
    car = models.OneToOneField(Car)
    last_checkup = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

I have created a custom CarManager that overrides models.Manager.create() to ensure the creation of CarProfile when a Car is created:

```
class CarManager(models.Manager):
    def create(self, **kwargs):
        with transaction.atomic():
            car = self.model(**kwargs)
            car.save(force_insert=True)
            CarProfile.objects.create(car=car)
        return car
```

When I call `Car.objects.create(make='Audi', model='R8')`, a new Car instance and its corresponding CarProfile is created as expected. However when I try creating a new Car using `Car.objects.update_or_create(make='Audi', model='R8')` or `Car.objects.get_or_create(make='Audi', model='R8')`, in both cases a Car instance is created but no corresponding CarProfile is created.

**Why doesn't [`update_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) and [`get_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create) produce the expected CarProfile instance when I've specified that behaviour in the custom `create() method`?**

It seems that both these methods are calling the `create()` from `QuerySet` class instead of my custom one.

Answer (score 4):

Django's `Manager` class is actually a `QuerySet` that has been [reconstituted](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/manager.py#L238) into a `Manager`. What if you implement `create` on a `QuerySet` and then build a `Manager` from that?

```
class CarQuerySet(models.QuerySet):

    def create(self, **kwargs):
        with transaction.atomic():
            car = self.model(**kwargs)
            car.save(force_insert=True)
            CarProfile.objects.create(car=car)
        return car
```

Then the `Car` is:

```
class Car(models.Mode):
    make = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=32)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('make', 'model',)

    objects = CarQuerySet.as_manager()
```

Comment: I've noticed how a Manager is really inherited from `BaseManager.from_queryset(QuerySet)`. I may be wrong, but it seems  [`from_queryset`](https://goo.gl/1L0x8N) and [`_get_queryset_methods`](https://goo.gl/uEssIf) create an ad-hoc Class for Manager to subclass which copies over any methods in `QuerySet` not defined in `BaseManager`. My `CarManager` class then subclasses that ad-hoc class so I'm confused as to why `create` is not overriding the one in `QuerySet` only for `update_and_create` and `get_or_create`.

Comment: Also, @Nathan Villaescusa, thank you for your response. I did end up creating a custom `CarQuerySet` and return an instance of it in `get_queryset` of `CarManager` (I've got other manager methods in there). `update_and_create` and `get_or_create` now have the correct behaviour. But I'm still wondering why my previous implementation did not work.

Answer (score 2):

The actual reason that overriding `create` is not working in this instance is because you need to override both the `update_and_create` and the `get_or_create` methods as well as `create` to affect their behaviour.

Comment: Why not overwrite `save` as it seems to be what they all have in common.

Answer (score 1):

Just want to clarify that this issue was addressed in Django v1.8a1. So now both `get_or_create` and `update_or_create` will call the managers `create` method as expected.

https://github.com/django/django/commit/0dce44e16be2d4850120cd333380ab9171c5964a